# How to generate source.jar of the public API of a closed source AAR?

Tags: android, kotlin, kdoc

We develop a closed sources library in Kotlin that is released as AAR. Unfortunatly our users can't see the KDoc (JavaDoc for Kotlin) in the IDE. Therefore we want to release the source of the public API only. The internals and the public API can be distingushed by there packages `foo.bar.api.*` and `foo.bar.internal.*`

Is this possible with gradle 3.4?

I found [Create Android library AAR including javadoc and sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531709/create-android-library-aar-including-javadoc-and-sources) but we don't want to include all sources.

Comment: Hi @chriss , Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @notsopopularguy yes we build a sources jar and include only the api packages

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you know already how to create and use the `javadoc` and `sources` artifacts. The [`Jar`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html) type only creates a special zip archive and copies the files for it. So you can exclude files as well:

```
task androidSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    baseName = artifact_id
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    exclude 'foo./bar/internal/**'
}
```