# How can I get source code of Android Library when using Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How can I get source code of Android Library  when using Android Studio?

I have try this,but nothing happened.

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea{
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/android

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Android Studio download dependencies sources and javadoc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426628/how-to-make-android-studio-download-dependencies-sources-and-javadoc)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can get all the Android source [here](https://android.googlesource.com).
2. In the Android Studio, you just need to press control(command in mac) on what function you want to check, it will take you to the source code.

Comment: Thank you!In fact,I mean especially third-part library.  If I press control or command,I will get only the class file,not the source code.There are only the function names and parameters

Comment: For third-part library, you need to google the function name, and it will give you API instruction, and maybe you get source code if it's an open source project(on github)

Comment: I know that method but it is not very convenient.And in fact,in gradle respository,there are source.jar and javadoc.jar.But is there any way to get it in a easy way?